# Правильная инициализация массива в Синглтоне

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, массивы, iphone

В синглтоне хочу сделать мутабельный массив для хранения в нем строковых объектов:

> ```
> Singleton.h
> ```

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *checkins;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *checkins;

+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton;

@end
```

> Singleton.m

```
@implementation Singleton

@synthesize checkins;

static Singleton * sharedSingleton = NULL;

+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton
{
    if (!sharedSingleton || sharedSingleton == NULL)
    {
        sharedSingleton = [Singleton new];
    }

    NSMutableArray *checkins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return sharedSingleton;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.example = nil;
    //[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Но инициализированный таким образом массив возвращает (null). Каким образом правильно реализовывается массив в синглтоне в obj-c?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Инициализируется как и любое свойство любого Objective-C класса.

Добавьте метод init

```
- (id)init {
    ...
    self.checkins = [NSMutableArray new];
    ...
}
```

В вашем же случае создается локальная переменная, которая удаляется сразу после выхода из метда `sharedSingleton`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за то что Вы есть на этом форуме! :)  Как всегда по делу и с разъяснениями

Answer (score 2):

```
+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton
{
    if (!sharedSingleton) {
        sharedSingleton = [Singleton new];
        _checkins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

Comment: неправильно, т.к. в статическом методе нету self (экземпляра класса ). 1101_debian Ответил верно

Comment: Ну он кагбы есть, только указывает на класс, а не на инстанс. Но в целом да, неправильно.

Comment: конечно же нет, инициализацию checkins нужно делать в init, как написал выше 1101_вуишфт

Comment: sharedSingleton.checkins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Можно вот так, но мне кажется что инициализация в `init` выглядит как-то чище.

Comment: Я бы вообще как-то так бы сделал:
{
+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton {
    static Singleton *sharedSingleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (sharedSingleton == nil){
            sharedSingleton = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    });
    
    return sharedSingleton;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.checkins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
}